# Why X-process is called a process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, gaussian-process

I have recently learnt about kernels in machine learning. And I have been introduced to many different processes e.g. Gaussian process, Wiener process. Now my question is why a set of functions has been named as a process? For example this is the definition of Gaussian process:

Let $\mu: X \to R$ be any function, $k: X \times X\to R$ be a Mercer kernel.
A Gaussian process $p(f) = GP(f;μ,k)$ is a probability distribution over the function $f : X \to R$, such that every finite restriction to function values $f_X :=[f_{x_1},...,f_{x_N}]$ is a Gaussian distribution $p(f_X)=N(f_X;μ_X,k_{XX})$.

Which parts exactly associates to a process??

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's called a process because it takes place over and can change over time. In the case of your examples, they are [stochastic processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process).

EDIT: As Benjamin says in a comment, the requirement isn't time, but that there is an indexing set, which could be time. It could also be spatial.

Comment: a process does not necessarily have to take place over/change over time, but there is some set that 'indexes' a collection of random variables. This set can be continuous (e.g. time) or discrete (e.g. a set of possible states like the 4 possible nucleotides in statistical genetics).